# how to display data from console angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller where i retrieve data by id from my `state` . How can i display those console data in my template?

```
app.controller('DetailCtrl', function($scope, $http, Inventory, Tags, User, $location, sharedService, inventoryItem) {  
console.log(inventoryItem);
};
```

Here is my state

```
.state('inventory.description',{
url:'/inventory/description/:id',
    views: {
        "descriptionview": {
            templateUrl: 'inventory/description.tpl.html',
            controller: 'DetailCtrl'
        }
    },
    data:{ pageTitle: 'DescriptionView'},
    resolve: {
        inventoryItem: function($stateParams, Inventory){
            return  Inventory.query({id: $stateParams.id});
    }
}
})
```

console retrieves data

```
Resource {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query:        function…}
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
barcode: "11234"
count: 22
cover: "/media/http%3A/api.bos.lv/media/static/images/no-image_1.png"
created: "2014-03-07T11:07:18.184465"
description: "LG monitor description"
id: 2
```

Comment: Where is your template and which property do you want to display?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this I think:

in your controller you can assign:

```
$scope.toDisplay = inventoryItem;
```

and in your template, add this where you want to display it:

```
{{toDisplay.barcode}}
```